# Present viewController from AppDelegate using UITabBarController design

Tags: objective-c, ios

My app is designed using a `UITabBarController` and im trying to present a view on top of that (a login screen) from the app delegate. When i use the following code:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Main_TabBarController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
Login_ViewController *lvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login_ViewController"];

[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:lvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I get the error `Warning: Attempt to present <Login_ViewController: 0x716fac0> on <UITabBarController: 0x7165240> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` and the screen is just  black. How do i add `Login_ViewController` to the window hierarchy?

Comment: @marciokoko I left it, moved on with other area's of my project, and later noticed it was working. Still dont know what issue was.

Comment: So you switched out view controllers from the AppDelegate using removeFromView? I had to use delegate call from one tab's viewDidLoad to dismiss the modally presented loginVC.

Answer (score 3):

You can always grab the current root viewcontroller and use it to present your login controller.

```
UIViewController *presentingController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
[presentingController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In addition, depending on how I want my login screen to look, I will push the login controller using UIModalPresentationFormSheet.

```
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

Comment: I still get the error `Warning: Attempt to present <Login_ViewController: 0x8e2f440> on <UITabBarController: 0x7145a10> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: Did you check the Files Owner Class assignment in your Main_TabBarController xib file?  I believe I have seen this error in the past when the xib file did not reference the correct controller class.

Answer (score 0):

You're using two different mechanisms for creating your UI.  You should move your tab bar controller into the storyboard.  When you instantiate your storyboard, it overwrites your window with a new instance and the first controller as the root controller.

The error message is telling you the tab bar controller's view is not in the view hierarchy, not the other way around.

I would create a controller with a view consisting of just your application logo and inside of this controller determine whether you need to go to the login screen or not (if you have persistent logins).  Then from the login screen transition to the tab bar controller.

Unless the storyboard you're loading isn't the main storyboard, you shouldn't need to load it manually.   You should be able to set the storyboard as the main one for the application and iOS will load it automatically.

Comment: The tabbarcontroller is in the storyboard and does present the first controller as the root controller... im trying to present a view controller on top of that..

Comment: If it is in the Storyboard, then why are you instantiating it from a separate Nib outside of the storyboard.

Comment: If the tab bar controller is in the storyboard, then make the login screen the first controller and transition to the tab bar controller upon successful login.  If you support persistent logins between sessions, you could try the approach I suggested.

Comment: I suppose that is incorrect and unnecessary, so how do i present a viewcontroller on top? Im still stuck on that

Comment: Well no i cant do that because theres time within the application where i may need to present it, so i need a way to do that

Comment: Then you would have the login controller as a separate controller with a modal transition from any controller that can present it.  Then you would request the transition from the storyboard and perform it.

Comment: Yeah thats what i need, i need to present it from the appdelegate

Comment: I would right a category for `UIViewController` with adding a method to determine if the login controller needs to be shown.  If it returns true, then present the login transition.  After the login completes, you dismiss your login controller and the calling controller is right there.